# Variable ImagePainter on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I'm working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose 1.0.0 and I'm trying to make a composable that uses a nullable image URL string and, if it's null, it will show a placeholder with `painterResource` and, if it's not null, it will display the actual image using `rememberImagePainter`.

The way I was doing that was:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun VariableImagePainterExample (
    imageURL: String?
) {
    val painter = rememberCoilPainter(
        null,
        previewPlaceholder = R.drawable.ic_placeholder_user,
        fadeIn = true,
    )

    LaunchedEffect(imageURL) {
        painter.request = imageURL
    }

    Image(painter = painter, contentDescription = null)
}
```

Unfortunately, the `rememberCoilPainter` became deprecated from accompanist-coil and it's suggested now to use the `rememberImagePainter`. However, the `ImagePainter.request` can't be changed like above. I then tried the following code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun VariableImagePainterExample (
    imageURL: String?
) {
    val painter = remember {
        mutableStateOf<ImagePainter>(painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_placeholder_user))
    }

    LaunchedEffect(imageURL) {
        painter.value = rememberImagePainter(imageURL)
    }

    Image(painter = painter.value, contentDescription = null)
}
```

But this doesn't work because `painterResource` and `rememberImagePainter` must be used on the `@Composable` function. How can i achieve the same effect as before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Coil **2.0.0** both `AsyncImage` and `rememberAsyncImagePainter` have `placeholder` parameter that takes any other painter:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = imageURL,
    placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.placeholder),
    contentDescription = null,
)
```

---

In Coil **1.4.0** you can use `builder` like this:

```
Image(
    rememberImagePainter(
        imageURL,
        builder = {
            placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = null,
)
```

Comment: Because the `imageURL` is nullable. At the first compose, the value would be null, until the http request is done and then the URL will be a string. I was using `LaunchedEffect` to check when the `imageURL` value is changed and, if it was, it would replace the painter with one that has the current image url

Comment: @MatheusDias this would do it anyway, that's how compose works. If `imageURL` is different from the last time composition, image view will discard old one and start downloading new one. And `null` can be passed to `rememberImagePainter` too without problems, it'll just be empty view. Also you can check `painter.state` to see what's there right now

Comment: I just checked here and it worked perfectly just as needed. I thought the `rememberImagePainter` would be static from the first parameters, but thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

**For Coil 2.2.+**
It has remeberAsyncImagePainter instead off rememberImagePainter

```
Image(painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = imageUrl,
                imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context).crossfade(true).build()),
                contentDescription = "images")
```